# Find and replace values in txt file with the data provided in another excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have an excel file like this:
[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulObD.png)

And another txt file like this:

.subckt blockA vdd vss A B C Out

xi01 vdd vss vdd vss x1 A inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4

xi02 vdd vss vdd vss x2 x1 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4

xi03 vdd vss vdd vss x3 x2 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4

xi04 vdd vss vdd vss x4 x3 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4

AS u can see the instance name xi01 is common in both excel and txt file. I want to replace the nfin_n = 4 and nfin_p = 4 values with the n device and p device value provided in the excel file.
So the output in this case should be a txt file with following text:
xi01 vdd vss vdd vss x1 A inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=6 nfin_p=6

I saw that people are making macros for the task and i have no idea on how to make a macro, i was wondering if i could write a simple function instead like def replace_n_and_p(excel file name,txt file name) and it would do all the replacement automatically.

Edit: The excel file and the notepad file are as follows:
[sample excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I61ef.png)

While the txt file is:
.subckt blockA vdd vss A B C Out
xi01 vdd vss vdd vss x1 A inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi02 vdd vss vdd vss x2 x1 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi03 vdd vss vdd vss x3 x2 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi04 vdd vss vdd vss x4 x3 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi05 vdd vss vdd vss net3 x4 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi06 vdd vss vdd vss x5 B inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi07 vdd vss vdd vss x6 x5 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi08 vdd vss vdd vss net4 x6 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
nand01 vdd vss vdd vss net3 net4 net5 nand
xi09 vdd vss vdd vss x7 C inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi010 vdd vss vdd vss x8 x7 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi011 vdd vss vdd vss x9 x8 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi012 vdd vss vdd vss net6 x9 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi013 vdd vss vdd vss x10 net5 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi014 vdd vss vdd vss x11 x10 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
xi015 vdd vss vdd vss net7 x11 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=4 nfin_p=4
nor01 vdd vss vdd vss net6 net7 Out nor
.ends

The above is just a sample.

Comment: You could try such thing as xlwings. It allow to make macros in python and call python functions inside excel.

Comment: @Vovin but i want to make changes in the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

import re

wb = xw.Book(r"cir1.xlsx")
app = wb.app
app.interactive = False
app.visible = False

df = wb.sheets.__iter__().__next__()["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, expand="table").value

PATTERN_ID = re.compile(r"xi\d+")
PATTERN_N = re.compile(r"(?<=nfin_n=)\d+")
PATTERN_P = re.compile(r"(?<=nfin_p=)\d+")
new_text = ""
with open("cir.txt") as textfile:
    for line in textfile:
        ID_match = re.search(PATTERN_ID, line)
        if ID_match:
            ID = ID_match.group()
            line = re.sub(PATTERN_N, fr"nfin_n={int(df.n_device[df.Instance_Name == ID])}", line)
            line = re.sub(PATTERN_P, fr"nfin_p={int(df.p_device[df.Instance_Name == ID])}", line)
        new_text += line
with open("cir.txt", "w") as textfile:
    textfile.write(new_text)

app.kill()
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, the output isnt the desired output with this code, i am getting the values of xi02 in the row of xi01, like this: 
.subckt blockA vdd vss A B C Out
xi01 vdd vss vdd vss x1 A inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=nfin_n=5 nfin_p=nfin_p=5
xi02 vdd vss vdd vss x2 x1 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=nfin_n=3 nfin_p=nfin_p=4
xi03 vdd vss vdd vss x3 x2 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=nfin_n=4 nfin_p=nfin_p=4
xi04 vdd vss vdd vss x4 x3 inv cpp=64n m=1 ln=22n lp=22n nf_n=1 nf_p=1 nfin_n=nfin_n=2 nfin_p=nfin_p=5

Comment: like nfin_n=nfin_n=5 nfin_p=nfin_p=5 should be with xi02 but with this code its with xi01.

Comment: @Pushpesh Could you send a link to either real txt & xlsx data or at least their little parts (10 rows for example). I tested this for 4 rows you presented hereinabove & it works.

Comment: i have updated the question with the real txt and xlsx data.

Comment: @Pushpesh could you attach _files_ to any cloud disk (Google, Drive, DropBox, whatever)? I definitely do not want to retype your image into excel.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1r2XXuWackdwwMQcrApcNoorMO30Sk1M2?usp=sharing  I hope this works